# Is it ok to add static reference to a service layer in Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

I am assessing the [Highway.Data.EntityFramework.Unity](http://nuget.org/packages/Highway.Data.EntityFramework.Unity/3.0.3.2) package in the context of a single project ASP.NET Web Forms application.

I want easy access to my service layer. Here is the relevant part of Global:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private static readonly IUnityContainer Container = new UnityContainer();

    public static IEmployeeService Service { get; private set; }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Container.BuildHighway();
        Container.RegisterType<IMappingConfiguration, EntityMapping>();
        Container.RegisterType<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>(
            new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>(
            new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterType<IDataContext, DataContext>(
            new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), 
            new InjectionConstructor("DataContext", new EntityMapping()));

        Service = Container.Resolve<IEmployeeService>();
    }
}
```

In my client, I can access like this:

```
this.Employees.DataSource = this.service.GetEmployees();
this.Employees.DataBind();
```

Works fine but I haven't taken this approach before and just because it appears to be ok... well, is it? If not, what do I do?

[Editited] For requested clarity.

Service:

```
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public EmployeeService(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return this.repository.Find(
            new AllEmployeesQuery())
            .ToList()
            .Select(ObjectMapper.Map<EmployeeEntity, Employee>);
    }
}
```

AllEmployeesQuery is a specification. Business object is mapped to EF entity by AutoMapper and vice-versa.

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: how can you access it with  this.service.GetEmployees(); ?? shouldn't it be Global.Service.GetEmployees()

Comment: That's correct, Global.Service.GetEmployees()

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid this approach like the plague. Do not share database connections or resources on an application level; it will lead to lousy performance and subtle bugs.

The best model I've found is to create a connection per request and store it in the current request to make the connection available to any other calls that might occur during the lifetime of the request.

The following code is a static property in our data layer. The default behavior is to instantiate a connection on the first get and store it in the request, and subsequent accesses of this property will return the previously created instance. The property also gives the user the ability to explicity override this in the cases where there is no HttpContext.

```
protected static dataLayer DataContext
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            if (StaticContext == null)
                StaticContext = new dataLayer();

            return StaticContext;
        }

        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["dataLayer"] == null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items["dataLayer"]= new dataLayer();

        return (dataLayer)HttpContext.Current.Items["dataLayer"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that the OP is trying to "share database connections or resources"?  It's not at all clear that `IEmployeeService` implies shared resources.

Comment: "create a connection per request and store it in the current request" - When do you release the resources held by the request? Please don't say GC.

Comment: The data/service layer implements idisposable and has a finalizer. When the request is completed it goes out of context.

Comment: The shared resource is a service layer, NOT a data layer. All the service layer does is receive and pass back business objects. A repository takes care of data access and where necessary, they are all wired up through Unity and a custom per HTTP request to make sure resources are discarded as necessary.

Comment: Then your question needs more detail, specifically, *how* does the service layer send & receive objects? Are objects instantiated on the same server, or remotely?

Comment: If your service layer is nothing more than a proxy, it's simply marshalling calls to a remote service and as long as those calls are not blocking your service thread then a shared reference should have little to no performance impact in creating a shared reference to your service.